# Implement I18n localization in Strapi local plugins

Tags: plugins, strapi

I generated a [local plugin](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/local-plugins-customization.html) and created an article model using:

```
"pluginOptions": {
  "i18n": {
    "localized": true
  }
},
```

inside his *article.settings.json* file, in order to make some specific fields translatables using the [Internationalization(I18N) plugin](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/i18n.html#installation)

Problem is, while running the command:

> strapi develop --watch-admin

I end up having the following errors:

> error Something went wrong in the model "Article" with the attribute "localizations"

> error TypeError: Cannot read property "uid" of undefined

Removing the "pluginOptions" instead, gives my local plugin running without any translatable field or articles__translations pivot that should be generated into my mysql database

"pluginOptions" is the very same parameter that gets generated into the model settings creating a collection type using the [Content-Types Builder](https://strapi.io/documentation/user-docs/latest/content-manager/introduction-to-content-manager.html#introduction-to-the-content-manager), but I can't have it to work  while using it for a local plugin.

Here is my article.settings.json:

> plugins/blog/models/article.settings.json

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "articles",
  "info": {
    "name": "article"
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": false,
    "timestamps": true,
    "populateCreatorFields": true,
    "increments": true,
    "comment": ""
  },
  "pluginOptions": {
    "i18n": {
      "localized": true
    }
  },
  "attributes": {
    "title": {
      "pluginOptions": {
        "i18n": {
          "localized": true
        }
      },
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "maxLength": 255,
      "minLength": 3
    },
    "slug": {
      "pluginOptions": {
        "i18n": {
          "localized": true
        }
      },
      "type": "uid",
      "targetField": "title",
      "required": true
    },
    "featured": {
      "pluginOptions": {
        "i18n": {
          "localized": false
        }
      },
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    },
    "published_date": {
      "pluginOptions": {
        "i18n": {
          "localized": false
        }
      },
      "type": "datetime"
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `content-type-builder` plugin as a workaround. You would not create the content type under the `content-types` folder but create it programmatically.

As an example of a very simple `tag` content type:

```
  {
    "singularName": "tag",
    "pluralName": "tags",
    "displayName": "tag",
    "description": "",
    "draftAndPublish": false,
    "pluginOptions": {
      "i18n": {
        "localized": true
      }
    },
    "attributes": {
      "label": {
        "type": "string",
        "pluginOptions": {
          "i18n": {
            "localized": true
          }
        },
        "unique": true
      }
    }
  }
```

Note, this schema of the json is a bit different from the ones in `plugin/server/content-types`.

Then you can create the content type programmatically like this:

```
import { Strapi } from "@strapi/strapi";
import tag from "../content-types/tag.json";
import page from "../content-types/page.json";

export default ({ strapi }: { strapi: Strapi }) => ({
  async createContentComponent() {
    if (!tag) return null;

    try {
      const components: any = [];

      const contentType = await strapi
        .plugin("content-type-builder")
        .services["content-types"].createContentType({
          contentType: tag,
          components,
        });

      return contentType;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error", e);
      return null;
    }
  },
});
```

This is exactly how the admin creates content types using the content builder UI.

And it works using the `pluginOptions.i18n.localized: true`.

One approach would be to do this, e.g., on the bootstrap phase of the plugin. Here you could also check whether or not the contents are created or not.

As a bonus, you can also create components that otherwise would not work.

Hope that helps.

Links:
Create components programmatically in a plugin: https://github.com/strapi/strapi-plugin-seo/blob/main/server/services/seo.js

Create content types:
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/88caa92f878a068926255dd482180202f53fcdcc/packages/core/content-type-builder/server/controllers/content-types.js#L48

EDIT:
You could also keep the original schema and use this fn to transform it - at least for now as long as the other approach is not working:

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/1eab2fb08c7a4d3d40a5a7ff3b2f137ce0afcf8a/packages/core/content-type-builder/server/services/content-types.js#L37